# Friction From an Object On-Top of a Sliding Object

Tags: classical-mechanics, friction

Consider a block $A$ lying on a flat and frictionless table, and a block $B$ lying on top of block $A$. A horizontal force $F$ is applied to block $A$. If there is no friction between blocks $A$ and $B$, then block $A$ will move in the direction of $F$ and $B$ will remain stationary until $A$ slides out from under it, at which point it will fall. If the friction between blocks $A$ and $B$ is nonzero, however, then block $B$ will move with block $A$ in the direction of $F$, as expected. While this result makes sense intuitively, and is consistent with out everyday experience, I've been unable to rationalize this behavior in terms of forces. If block $B$ is moving along with block $A$, then there must be some force acting on $B$ (it started out at rest, after all), and my teacher said this force is a frictional which is equal to $F$. This seems strange, considering my previous experience with friction, which I understand to be a force that *opposes motion*, not one that causes it. How is it possible that there could be a frictional force acting on $B$ if there is no other force acting on it? Perhaps my understanding of friction is too narrow, but I do not see how we can mathematically or logically justify why friction would be causing motion in a body that is otherwise not subject to any forces.

Comment: "...which is as a force that opposes motion,..."  Try "Opposes RELATIVE motion"

Comment: Hmm, so my understanding really was too narrow! Thank you, this makes much more sense now.